# Laravel Vue router axios

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-router

I'm already doing a project in laravel and I'm added vue router to it.  after add "mode:'history" it remove the "#" but after if I refresh the page it says 404 error. so I add this line to web.php

```
Route::get('/{any}', 'HomeController@index')->where('any', '.*');
```

after that it fixed the refresh issue but now my Axios request not working.. all Axios request reposed gave the home page.. how can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `any` route should be the last route entry in your router file.
Laravel routing honors top down registration of Routes, it will use the first match it finds.

If that `any` wildcard entry is at the top of the Laravel router file then anything written after (below it) will be ignored.

```php
Route::get('/example-1', 'HomeController@exampleOne'); // Will work

// If nothing else above this line matches then run Vue App
Route::get('/{any}', 'HomeController@index')->where('any', '.*');

// Anything written here will be ignored.
Route::get('/example-2', 'HomeController@exampleTwo') // Not work
```